# SQLite, bash script, and concatenate operator

Tags: bash, sqlite

I have a SQLite database, stuff.db (with TABLE notes (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, timeStamp DATE, note TEXT);). The timeStamp is automatically triggered.

I want to populate it the quick and dirty way from the command line.

So, I have written a script named bashscript1 which goes :

```
sqlite3 script.db 'insert into notes (note) values ("Stuff happens.");'
```

But I wanted both to keep this sentence as the standard entry and if necessary, to be more precise : I would like to add variable information such as : "Foo enters the room." or "Bar makes a phone call.". The idea is to concatenate those strings and have : "Stuff happens. Foo enters the room." or "Stuff happens. Bar makes a phone call."

So I rewrote the script :

```
echo "Do you want to add somme text ?"
read Str1
sqlite3 script.db 'insert into notes (note) values ("Stuff happens."||\"$Str1\");'
```

And, of course I got an error message.
How should I proceed ?

Thanks in advance

ThG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shell variables wont expand when wrapped in single-quotes like you have it.  Perhaps you want:

```
sqlite3 script.db "insert into notes (note) values (\"Stuff happens.\"||\"$Str1\");"
```

P.S.
I'm assuming the `||` is part of the sqlite3 syntax because it certainly isn't bash, at least not in that context.  If that's not right, let me know.

Comment: I confirm that || is the concatenate operator in sqlite. But as with sje397 I get an error message : Error: unrecognized token: "\"

Comment: @SiegeX : Would'nt it be a better solution to concatenate the 2 strings in bash before sending it to sqlite ? But I do not know how to do that ...(same mesg to sje397)

Comment: It would be better not to get in to the quote-soup business and do it this way: `sqlite3 script.db 'insert into notes (note) values ("Stuff happens."||"'"$Str1"'");'`. I know it's a bit hypocritical to call this "not quote-soup" but this is the most reliable method.

Comment: @Sorpigal : that worked perfectly (but I must admit I don't grasp the logic of single quotes embedded in double quotes embedded in single quotes...). Thanks a lot. ThG

Comment: @ThG Look at Sorpigal's line in parts *delimited* by the single quotes. The first part is `'insert into notes (note) values ("Stuff happens."||"'`. Since it's in single quotes that is a literal line not to be expanded or changed by the shell, i.e. the double quotes are literal.  The next part is `"$Str1"` which is surrounded by double quotes telling the shell go ahead and expand `$Str1`. Finally, the last part is `'");'` which is again a literal string due to the single quotes.  This method allows you to manually turn on & off shell expansion.

Comment: @SiegeX A late answer. I think I begin (this should be between quotes...) to understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sqlite3 script.db "insert into notes (note) values ('Stuff happens.$Str1');"
```

Note that this will break if your `$Str1` contains a single quote.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I get in sqlite an error message : Error: unrecognized token: "\"

Comment: sorry, I am rather new.. What did you mean by Edited ? I hope I did not forget something. BTW, would'nt it be a better solution to concatenate the 2 strings in bash before sending it to sqlite ? But I do not know how to do that ...(same mesg to SiegeX)

Comment: @ThG - I'm kinda new too :) I edited my answer - it looks to me like the single quotes work in a test script I tried, and the syntax for SQLite expects single quotes around strings.